# Extract zip folders to same named folders using 7 zip

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I've below batch commands which does not extract data from zip folders to same named folders. It just extract for one and other 2 are extracted at main dir.

**Code:**

```
for /R "C:\extract" %%I in ("*.7z_encrpt") do ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" X -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI")
for /R "C:\extract" %%I in ("*.zip_encrpt") do ("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" X -y -o"%%~dpI" "%%~fI")
```

**Input:**

test1.zip_encrypt

test2.7z_encrypt

test3.7z_encrypt

**Output:**

test2

Contents from test1

Contents from test3

**Desired output:**

test1

test2

test3

Comment: If your output is supposed to be named as the file, you should be using `"%%~dpnI"`.

Comment: Yeah, it's working fine now. Thank you. You can post this as an answer.

Comment: @Compo But with above changes, now for other files/folders having .7z or .zip 
 extension output is `out1 -> out1 -> Contents`. Is any way to handle this?

Comment: IIUR the double `out1` is because the `x` option restores pathes already in the `.7z/.zip` archives, there is AFAIK no way without  prior testing or moving afterwards.